# Observable which reads a stream until it ends or there is an error

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Using reactive extensions, how can I create an Observable which will continuously call the Read method on a stream and propagate the result to its observers?

Or is this the completely wrong way of approaching things? Should I be implementing my own IObservable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never hit a circumstance where implementing my own observable makes sense.

Try this instead:

```
public static IObservable<byte[]> ObservableRead(Stream stream, int bufferSize)
{
    return Observable.Create<byte[]>(o =>
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        var read = 0;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                var results = buffer.Take(read).ToArray();
                //Always return a copy
                //never the buffer for concurrency's sake.
                o.OnNext(results);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            o.OnError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            o.OnCompleted();
        }
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is good, but it only runs when there is a subscription. What if I want to have multiple subscribers and have it running all the time? I believe I need to use Observer.Generate instead. Trying to figure it out now.

Comment: @NoPyGod - You don't want multiple subscribers to the one stream. Each would compete to get bytes. You need a single reading stream that you could publish to multiple subscribers. Or you could read the file into memory and move that around. Ideally your signature should be `IObservable<byte[]> ObservableRead(Func<Stream> streamFactory, int bufferSize)` for this kind of method to be properly functional.

Comment: Why do you call `OnCompleted()` in `finally`? Wouldn't it work the same if you put it at the end of the `try`?

Comment: @svick - Yes, you're right. I'll claim that it is for readability. ;-)

Comment: I do want multiple subscribers to the same stream. I want to achieve this by having a single observerable read the stream and then multiple observables on that observable. THey wont compete for bytes if the observable does its job correctly.

Comment: @NoPyGod - Then you should use the `Publish` method. That's what it is used for. You should never try to implement your own `IObservable`. If you try to make the observable hold state and manage multiple observers then you are making your job very difficult. Use the built-in operators. They will help keep your code safe.